# What if i dont want any crop dusting done near my home simply because of the cancer causing affects from the chemicals being spayed right on top of me

Tags: safety

I have 8 acres and I am surrounded by farmland that gets sprayed regularly every year! Twice while driving down my road, the plane flew right over top of me and splattered my entire car with spray chemicals! And once while working in my yard, I smelled it first, then I felt a wet light mistyspray on my arms, and was visible on my jeans!! I don't want any crop dusting near my property for that reason alone..can I stop them, there are other ways of application, I feel threatened by these health hazardous chemicals on top of me year after year..what can I do to stop them?

Comment: This is primarily a legal problem and not an aviation problem.

Comment: How do you know these chemicals are "health hazardous"? Do you even know what the chemicals are? You have to find out what is being sprayed, and document the dates and times, and provide photos or witnesses. Then you can complain to your local lawman.

Comment: I agree this is not an aviation question.  But as with many of these things, the very first step I believe is to identify the landowner and discuss your concerns with them.  It is possible you'll get the "whatever."  But its also possible they'll be concerned and feel it is their responsibility to discuss it with the application company that they aren't being considerate enough of neighbors.  And if you don't get satisfaction and decide to take it up with your township or county, it will matter to them that you already made an attempt to clear things up with the owner and were rebuffed.

Comment: Peggy, it may not be worth your effort now, but you could edit your question to ask about aviation regulations specific to crop dusting and get the question reopened in case you think there might be benefits in getting any additional perspective on your issue.  The existing answer is ready-made for such an edit, and could be accepted unless somebody else chimes in with something better.  A succinct, regulation based Q&A that is searchable might be a good thing to have for the record...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a pertinent Federal Aviation Regulation:

[14 CFR Part 137.37 Manner of dispensing.](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-G/part-137/subpart-C/section-137.37)

> No persons may dispense, or cause to be dispensed, from an aircraft, any material or substance in a manner that creates a hazard to persons or property on the surface.

Look up the information for the FAA's Flight Standards District Office (FSDO) that services where you live. They would have FAA regulatory oversight of all of the "crop duster" operations in their area of jurisdiction. This would be a good place to start.

Also, there are likely some state or local agencies that have responsibilities associated with pesticide (or similar) dispensing operations.

Comment: The state Dept of Agriculture would be another regulatory agency to check with.